# Supercluster Returning Unexpected Longitude Values

Tags: javascript, html, geojson

I'm using the supercluster package to calculate clusters to show on a map using the React version of leaflet. The individual locations I am trying to cluster have latitudes of around -34 to -42 and longitude values of around 172 to 174, however the calculated clusters, while their latitude values seem correct, are given longitude values of around 5 to 7.

[Clusters vs Individual Locations](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mFXeI.png) The black pin is the cluster, the green pin is the remaining individual site in its correct location.

The code used to calculate the sites:

```html
const clusterer = new Supercluster<GeoJSONSiteProperties, {}>({ radius: 30 })
const geoJSONSites = sites.map(site => representSiteAsGeoJSON(site))
clusterer.load(geoJSONSites)

//The clusterer will determine which sites are far enough from others to display individually,
//and which should be put in a cluster represented by a pin on the map. Once it has done that
//sort the indidual sites and clusters and update the state to display them on the map. const newClusters: ClusterFeature<{}>[] = []
const newIndividualSites: ISite[] = []
    
clusterer.getClusters([-180, -85, 180, 85 ], mapZoomLevel).forEach((c: GeoJSONSite | ClusterFeature<{}>) =>{

if(c.properties.cluster){
    newClusters.push(c as ClusterFeature<{}>)
}
else{
    newIndividualSites.push(createSiteFromGeoJSONRepresentation(c as GeoJSONSite))
}

})
```

The code that converts the sites to and from geoJSON:

```html
import { Feature, Point } from 'geojson';
import { ISite } from '../model/definitions/data_providers/ISitesProvider';

export type GeoJSONSiteProperties = Omit<ISite, "lat" | "lon"> & { cluster: false }

export type GeoJSONSite = Feature<Point, GeoJSONSiteProperties>

/**
 * Create a representation of a site in the GeoJSON format.
 * @param site
 * @returns 
 */
export function representSiteAsGeoJSON(site: ISite): GeoJSONSite {

    return {
        type: "Feature",
        geometry: {
            type: "Point",
            coordinates: [ site.lat, site.lon ]
        },
        properties: {
            cluster: false,
            roadPositionString: site.roadPositionString,
            postedSpeedLimit: site.postedSpeedLimit,
            hasSampleImages: site.hasSampleImages,
            stations: site.stations,
            address: site.address
        }
    }

}

export function createSiteFromGeoJSONRepresentation(geojsonSite: GeoJSONSite): ISite{

    return {
        
        lat: geojsonSite.geometry.coordinates[0],
        lon: geojsonSite.geometry.coordinates[1],
        
        ...geojsonSite.properties
        
    }

}
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening?

Answer (score 1):

Stumbled across this today and was having the same problem.

It seems in GeoJSON it expects points in X,Y ... which means

`coordinates: [ site.lat, site.lon ]`

is reversed and needs to be ...

`coordinates: [ site.lon, site.lat ]`

And the same goes where its being converted from GeoJSON back to your model